# Unity3D InvokeRepeating()

Tags: unity3d

```
private void Start()
{
   InvokeRepeating("FreeCharacterSpawnerSettings", 0f, 10f);
}
private void FreeCharacterSpawnerSettings()
{
    if (!activeScene)//переменная которая обозначает начало игры
        return;
    Instantiate(freeCharacter.model, spawnerPlace.transform);
}
```

Почему-то InvokeRepeating() вызывает метод чаще чем в 10 секунд при этом остальные InvokeRepeting() работают в скрипте корректно.
Что делать? Может я что-то упускаю?

Comment: Возможно где-то ещё запуск этого метода есть